# Geofire queries that last long in Firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, geofire

I'm writing an alert system that push notifies people when they enter a certain area. I'm using GeoFire to run the geoquery from a Firebase cloud function. The thing is that I need the geoquery to remain open for as long as the alert is active, so I'm cancelling it with a setTimeout, with a duration that can last for some hours. I know functions should be kept short, less than a minute or so. Any idea on how to keep the geoquery alive in a cloud function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to keep a GeoFire listener active in a Cloud Function for Firebase.

What you could do is a [trigger a function from a regular Realtime Database update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) and then check of the updated data falls into your range.